# How client server and deployed Java code connects each other?

Tags: java, web, web-applications, client-server

Generally we learnt through ***http connection client server*** connection happens,

- My question is we deploy `.class` files in server say ***tomcat***, do
  ***tomcat*** understands `.class` files?

  As I learnt `.class` files are ***byte code*** understood by **jvm** means as per my understanding everything(protocal-webserver-javacode ) first converts to ***binary code*** and then communicates with each other,correct me if I'm wrong if so then please explain me in details and links to read more on it ?

Comment: There are many online content available on this, you can search and get easily. Do visit to https://www.javatpoint.com/internal-details-of-hello-java-program for simple explanation. For more detail read documention.

Comment: Class files aren't deployed to application servers like Tomcat. Web archives are. There is a lot of material regarding how they communicate. On the other hand, client/server architecture is too generic, so it isn't really possible to explain how communication works at that level. Are you intersted in links about how appication servers like Tomcat work?